# Swift if let statement results in <<error type>> instead of custom object

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to use `if let` Swift statement to use an optional if it's not equal to `nil`. But for some reason, when I use it, Xcode shows the object is `<>z

I have a function which returns `MyObject?` and I want to check if it is nil, and if it's not I want to use it.

I'm trying to do it like this:

```
if let anObject = self.myFunc() {
   anObject //Xcode shows that anObject is not MyObject but <<error type>>
}
```

(I'm using `SwiftUI` if that matters)

Does anyone knows why?

Comment: Did you mean `self.myFunc()` since it's a function?

Comment: @Larme Yes, you're right. I'll edit the question

Comment: Would you show more code of context in which you use that expression?

Comment: @Asperi I'm trying to use in inside `var body: some View` and in order to determinate if to add a view or not (based on if `anObject` is nil or not)

Comment: SwiftUI depends on the unofficial (so far) Swift function builder feature, which relies on doing a transformation of the SwiftUI code you write, and turning into a series of function calls. Unfortunately, it doesn't support all syntax, like `if let`, and loops, a fair few other syntax forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if let` is not allowed within `body` as is, so if you just need to conditionally shown some view on result of function, then the solution will be

```
if self.myFunc() != nil {
  // some view here
}
```